# Client Certificate not negotiated after server restart

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-express

I'm using IIS Express 8 while my project is in development. I have a company certificate in the Personal folder of the computer account and several client certificates in the Personal folder of the current user account. I've successfully installed these using the mmc tool. I mapped the certificate and port for ssl with this command:

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 appid={} certstorename=MY certhash=some hash clientcertnegotiation=enable

When I run the app through VS, I am correctly prompted to choose a client certificate. However, when I restart my machine and run the app again, I am no longer prompted for the client certificate. Deleting the mapping and re adding it solves the problem..... unitl I restart again. OK, I have a workaround but it is far from ideal - I sense I'm missing something somewhere.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK I sorted it now. The root CA certificate was NOT in the trust authorities store, but in Personal. For some reason this runs fine when adding the certificate (perhaps it's picking up the root CA certificate when running the netsh sslcert add command and caching it?).

This post helped me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2011/11/15/troubleshooting-403-7-client-certificate-required-errors-amp-step-by-step-to-make-sure-your-client-certificate-is-displayed-and-selected.aspx